# Checking whether the user is using an iPhone or and iPad in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been looking around for a while, and I cannot figure out how to check whether the user has an iPad or an iPhone?

I am using Xamarin.Forms, and I have no need to check whether the Android device is a tablet or phone as the issue does not resolve around Android.

---

Code which I have found that could be helpful:

```
var idiom = UIKit.UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom;
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why do you need to know whether it's an iPhone or an iPad? That's usually the wrong approach.

Comment: @rmaddy Because when I create a MasterDetailPage for iPad, instead of the animation that is shown on iPhone (where the Detail page slides over to the right with the master (menu) - which is what I want) it has an animation where the master (menu) page slides on top of the detail page. If you have a solution for this problem I would be extremely grateful :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can check this by using the [Device Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/device/) in Xamarin.Forms

```
if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
{
    // iPad
}

if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
{
    // iPhone
}
```

This is a multi-platform solution that works for Android, iOS and Windows Phone.

If you need to make differences in XAML files you can use the **OnIdiom** tag like this:

```
<StackLayout>
   <StackLayout.Padding>
      <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
          <OnIdiom.Phone>
              10
          </OnIdiom.Phone>
          <OnIdiom.Tablet>
              20
          </OnIdiom.Tablet>
      </OnIdiom>
   </StackLayout.Padding>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Device.Idiom does not work for me on IOS SDK 12.2.

This does:

```cs
using UIKit;

UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone // or Pad
```

To be exact, Device.Idiom returns TargetIdiom.Unsupported, for iPhone SE and iPhone XR.